# Sanitizing parameters passed from url to iframe src attribute

Tags: javascript, iframe, websecurity

On *domain-one.com* an iframe elements get written through javascript with the code below.
The src attribute url of that iframe needs to receive the url parameters that are given to *domain-one.com*

e.g. 
`domain-one.com?par1=value1&par2=value2`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var params = window.location.search.substring(1);

  if (params && params.length > 0) {
    document.write('<iframe src="https://example.com/page?col=2&' + params + '"></iframe>');
  }
  else {
    document.write('<iframe src="https://example.com/page"></iframe>');
  }

</script>
```

With this code any number of params and any value can be given to domain-one.com. 
This feels rather unsecure.

What is best practice to minimize the risks? Does this needs escaping or encoding? 
What vulnerability can be executed client side by using the code above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var uri = "example?withParams=?;` and then `var res = encodeURI(uri);` is what I would do.

Comment: Biggest problem might be the fact that you're writing an HTML string instead of setting the attribute with `.src`, but even still, brackets are escaped, so eg having `?</iframe>` will result in `.search` being `?%3C/iframe%3E`. It might be safe for *this particular situation*, but it's still ugly, better to set the `src` of the iframe instead